# ERROR in Biostrings while trying to MSA using ggmsa

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to do a msa of the same peptide in 3 species (rat, zebrafish, and pupfish) and match it (found identical identities/disparities) with 2 synthetic peptides that I have (M35 and M871) but I'm getting the following error after building the vector:

```
Library (ggmsa)
galanin_table <- c("MACSKHLVLFLTILLSLAETPDSAPAHRGRGGWTLNSAGYLLGPVLHLSSKANQGRKTDSALEILDLWKAIDGLPYSRSPRMTKRSMGETFVKPRTGDLRIVDKNVPDEEATLNL", "Rat", "MHRCVGGVCVSLIVCAFLTETLGMVIAAKEKRGWTLNSAGYLLGPRRIDHLIQIKDTPSARGREDLLGQYAIDSHRSLSDKHGLAGKREMPLDEDFKTGALRIADEDVVHTIIDFLSYLKLKEIGALDSLPSSLTSEEISQP", "Zebrafish", "MQRSFAVFCVSLIFCATLSETIGLVIAAKEKRGWTLNSAGYLLGPRRIDHLIQIKDSPSARGRDELVNQYGIDGHRTLGDKAGLAGKRDMAQEDDVRTGPLRIGDEDIIHTVIDFLSYLKLKEMGALDSLPSPLTSDELANP", "Pupfish", "GWTLNSAGYLLGPPPGFSPFR","M35", "WTLNSAGYLLGPEHPPPALALA","M871")

galanin_matrix <- matrix(galanin_table, byrow=T, nrow=5)
galanin_table <- as.data.frame(galanin_matrix, stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(galanin_table) <- c("Sequences", "Species")
galanin_table <- as.data.frame(galanin_table)
galanin_list <- as.list(galanin_table)
galanin_asvector <- as.vector(galanin_list)
galanin_asvector_ss <- Biostrings::AAStringSet(x= galanin_asvector)
```

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function 'seqtype' for signature '"character"'

Probably I'm building the vector in the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

You've certainly started out with an interesting approach for importing your sequences into R. `ggmsa()` expects either a system file identifying sequences in a recognized format like FASTA, or a XStringSet object of your sequences. I don't know if you've actually stored your sequences in a character string, or that was just an easy avenue for including them here in this example, but assuming that's what you've got this should get you started:

```
# load in decipher for the aligner
suppressMessages(library(DECIPHER))
# load in ggmsa
library(ggmsa)

# your sequences
galanin_table <- c("MACSKHLVLFLTILLSLAETPDSAPAHRGRGGWTLNSAGYLLGPVLHLSSKANQGRKTDSALEILDLWKAIDGLPYSRSPRMTKRSMGETFVKPRTGDLRIVDKNVPDEEATLNL", "Rat", "MHRCVGGVCVSLIVCAFLTETLGMVIAAKEKRGWTLNSAGYLLGPRRIDHLIQIKDTPSARGREDLLGQYAIDSHRSLSDKHGLAGKREMPLDEDFKTGALRIADEDVVHTIIDFLSYLKLKEIGALDSLPSSLTSEEISQP", "Zebrafish", "MQRSFAVFCVSLIFCATLSETIGLVIAAKEKRGWTLNSAGYLLGPRRIDHLIQIKDSPSARGRDELVNQYGIDGHRTLGDKAGLAGKRDMAQEDDVRTGPLRIGDEDIIHTVIDFLSYLKLKEMGALDSLPSPLTSDELANP", "Pupfish", "GWTLNSAGYLLGPPPGFSPFR","M35", "WTLNSAGYLLGPEHPPPALALA","M871")

# grab your sequnces, c(T,F) will recycle over the original vector to select
# a 1,3,5,7,etc pattern
# conversely c(F,T) can grab the names in the opposite pattern
seqs <- AAStringSet(galanin_table[c(T,F)])
names(seqs) <- galanin_table[c(F,T)]

# align your sequences
ali <- AlignSeqs(seqs)

# call ggmsa
ggmsa(msa = ali,
      color = "Clustal", 
      font = "DroidSansMono",
      char_width = 0.5,
      seq_name = TRUE)
```

Good luck!